# Sync Poetry with PIP

Tags: python, pip, python-poetry

I have a virtual environment created with **Poetry** where I had installed some packages with **pip** (Airflow and their dependencies). When I execute `pip list`, I see all the packages installed.

I didn't install Airflow with Poetry because is not supported: https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/

I want to update Poetry with all the installed packages with PIP, but I don't know how to do this. When I execute `poetry show` I don't see any of the packages installed.

There is a way of updating the **poetry.lock** with the current packages installed in the active environment? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, because poetry does the locking without taking into account the current environment. It just takes the information from the `pyproject.toml` and tries to find a solution that is valid in any case.